# Read .dat file in C++ whose data is of type Class, then store each line in a vector of type Class

Tags: c++, class, vector, fstream

Let's say I have a .dat file called `numbers.dat` which consists of a list of integers like so:

```
1
44
2
5
```

and so on.

Then to read from this .dat file and place each number in a vector of type `int`, I know what to do:

```
std::ifstream file("numbers.dat");
int x;
std::vector<int> integers;
while(file >> x)
{
    integers.push_back(x);
}
file.close
```

Now if I want to output each integer I just need to loop over the vector, doing a `cout` each time.

But in my case, I have a .dat file called `food.dat` with multiple data types on each line separated by tab characters, for example

```
Eggs    Eg    1    1.2
Spam    Spm   2    1.5
```

and so on.

I have created a class called Food, with the fields `name`, `symbol`, `number`, and `cost`, which are of type `string`, `string`, `int`, and `double` respectively. Now, if I try the same as before, but with the appropriate changes:

```
std::ifstream file("food.dat");
Food f;     // the constructor for Food handles default values
std::vector<Food> vec;
while(file >> f)
{
    vec.push_back(f);
}
file.close;
```

I get the compiler error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression('std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char') and Food)
while (file >> f)
```

So I tried something else, this time I am just trying to read the first line in the file to check that it works.

```
std::ifstream file("food.dat");
Food f;
file >> f;
file.close();
```

But this gives the same compiler error as before. I have found that the code snippet `file >> f` is the part that the compiler complains about in both cases.

How can I avoid this error and make the code compile? My intention is to output each element of the vector (I have already correctly overloaded the `<<` operator to handle this for variables of type Food).

Should I overload the "get from" operator, `>>` for variables of type Food in order to make the code compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I avoid this error and make the code compile?

You need to define a function

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Food& f) { ... }
```

appropriately.

E.g.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Food& f)
{
   return in >> f.name >> f.symbol >> f.number >> f.coset;
}
```

Comment: So the problem was that I didn't specify what to do if the >> operator is used with an object of type Food.
Should this always be done when using operators on objects of non-primitive type?

Comment: @Joel : yes. You need to define how to handle anything except primitives. How could the compiler know how you want it handled otherwise?